# Convert element text to object in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, string, protractor

I have a span tag that has a json as its text and i'm trying to use that text and convert it to an object in protractor so I can use it for testing.

```
{"type":"msax-cc-error","value":[{"Code":22104,"Message":"Card holder is required"},{"Code":22058,"Message":"Card number is required"},{"Code":22109,"Message":"Card type is not supported"},{"Code":22103,"Message":"Expiration year is required"}]}
```

is there a way to convert this get to an object in protractor? Currently I have it as this, but seems to be not working.

```
it('Submitting should be ignored and prompt appropriate error code', function() {
    //assign the element text to a variable
    var response = element(by.css('.message-box .message-in')).getText();
    expect(response.type).toBe('msax-cc-error');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform [`getText()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) operation on an element, it returns the element's text in the form of string. In order to use the result as an object, you have to convert the string into an object using [`JSON.parse()`](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) function. Here's how to do it -

```
var response;
element(by.css('.message-box .message-in')).getText().then(function(text){
    response = JSON.parse(text);
    expect(response.type).toBe('msax-cc-error');
});
```

Hope it helps.